# Unicode-aware word-boundary in perl

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I'm on perl-5.24 and I stumbled upon `\b` being not unicode aware:

```
$ echo '""test"" ""тест""' | perl -pe 's/""\b/“/g'
“test"" ""тест""
```

where as I expected it to be `“test"" “тест""`.

Then I learned about unicode extensions in perl-5.22.1 regex, in particular this one: `\b{wb}`. But with these extensions I still get wrong results:

```
$ echo '""test"" ""тест""' | perl -pe 's/""\b{wb}/“/g'
“test“ “тест“
```

where as I expected it to be `“test"" “тест""`.

My question is: who do I transform `""test"" ""тест""` to `“test"" “тест""` via perl regex?

Comment: @ikegami: yeap, I'm passing UTF-8. But isn't world is mostly UTF-8 now?

Comment: No, the world works with decoded text (`String` instead of `byte[]`, `Reader`s over `Stream`s, etc). That way, they are encoding-agnostic, and they can be much simpler since they don't worry about the encoded-width of a character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You told `s///` to match against the following:

```
22.22.74.65.73.74.22.22.20.22.22.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.22.22.A
```

`s///` (or more specifically, `\b`), expects Unicode Code Points, so that means the above is treated as

```
""test"" ""Ñ<82>ÐµÑ<81>Ñ<82>""
```

That's obviously not what you want the string to be.

---

Similarly, you claim your code contains the following:

```
s/""\b/“/g
```

Perl expects the script to be encoded using ASCII unless you encode the script using UTF-8 and add `use utf8;` to let it know.

---

**Decode inputs. Encode outputs.**

```
$ echo '""test"" ""тест""' | perl -pe'
    use utf8;
    use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
    s/""\b/“/g
'
“test"" “тест""
```

or

```
$ echo '""test"" ""тест""' | perl -CSDA -Mutf8 -pe's/""\b/“/g'
“test"" “тест""
```

Comment: Technically, `Ñ` is also a `\w` char, so the `\b` should match, but it doesn't because of a bug in Perl that's fixed by adding `use feature qw( unicode_strings );` or `use 5.014;`. I didn't mention this because this bug in Perl is rendered moot once we fix your problem the right way.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll use `-CSDA -Mutf8` from this day on.